# What is an elegant solution to make multiple xor comparisons in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, xor

I need to filter a dataset according to multiple, mutually exclusive conditions. The `xor` operator seems useful for this case, but it feels a bit awkward to use in the `dplyr::filter` function. The other logical operators (`|`, `&`, `==`, etc.) allow me to chain the comparisons, but I have not found a way to do that with `xor`. Here are the two approaches I could think of:

```
library(tidyverse)

#a)
Orange %>%
  filter(xor(Tree == 1, xor(circumference == 75, age == 1582)))

#b)
Orange %>%
  filter((Tree == 1 & !(circumference == 75) & !(age == 1582)) |
         (Tree != 1 &   circumference == 75  & !(age == 1582)) |
         (Tree != 1 & !(circumference == 75) &   age == 1582))
```

Both seem a bit complicated. In my dataset I need to test five conditions and the nested version a) becomes confusing. It also follows a very different pattern from other types of comparisons. Approach b) is bloated and increases the risk of typos.

I thought that something in the form of the `%in%` operator could be useful, like `%xor%`, but it does not seem to exist:

```
library(tidyverse)

Orange %>%
  filter(Tree == 1 %xor% circumference == 75 %xor% age == 1582)
```

What would be a more elegant approach than a) or b) that actually works?

Comment: You could see `?Reduce`. I guess in the dplyr context i could be something like `Orange %>% filter(list(Tree == 1, circumference == 75, age == 1582) %>% reduce(xor))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the explicit conversion of booleans to integers to just look where the vectorized sum of the 3 logical checks you're doing is 1.

```r
Orange %>%
  filter((Tree == 1) + (circumference == 75) + (age == 1582) == 1)
```